# How is Privileged identity management (PIM) different from privileged access management (PAM)?

Tags: access-control, identity, active-directory, pam

I am very confused about those two, I was trying to understand the difference but it all sounds the same from what I read online.

Answer (score 1):

An identity says who you are while authorization is concerned with validating someones mandate, aka the individual permissions to specific application functionality, data, or service.

Authenticating a person focuses on letting someone prove who they are. One identity can for example be linked to multiple accounts where each account can have different permissions within the system.